# How to navigate back, returning some data, without knowing which page the user came from

Tags: navigation, ionic4, router

I have a page that can be navigated to by more than one "parent/origin" page.

Something like this:

```
Page 1 \
        \
Page 2 -- Page 4
        /
Page 3 /
```

I need to return some data from Page 4 to it's parent (the origin page).

I've been using `this.navCtrl.back()` to navigate back on the rest of the application, but this time I need to return some data and it seems that it is not possible using this function.

I know it is possible to pass data using `this.navCtrl.navigateBack(['page-1'], extras)`, but I would need to know which page the user came from. Is there any easy way of doing this?

I know I can pass the name of the origin page on the extras when going to Page 4, but it doesn't seem so correct (what is your opinion?).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the context of your app, could `Page 4` be a [modal page](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)? That way it'd be easy to return data to whatever page is calling it.

Comment: I guess it could but its better to be a separate page.

Comment: It'd still be a separate page, but it'd be *opened as a modal*. That's the only difference and the advantage of this approach is that you can return data from the modal very easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments, this looks like the perfect scenario to use **[modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal)**. That way `Page 4` could return data to the caller even without knowing what page has created/presented it.

The code could be something like this:

**Page 1 / Page 2 / Page 3:**

```
// Angular
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { ModalController, OverlayEventDetail } from '@ionic/angular';

// Modal page
import { ModalPage } from '../modal/modal.page';

@Component({ ... })
export class ModalExample {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController) {}

  async presentModal() {
    // create the modal
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalPage,
        componentProps: {
            'firstName': 'Douglas',
            'lastName': 'Adams',
            'middleInitial': 'N'
        }
    });

    // handle the data returned by the modal
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((detail: OverlayEventDetail) => {
      if (detail !== null) {
        console.log('The result: ', detail.data);
      }
    });

    // present the modal
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

**Page 4**

```
// Angular
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

// Ionic
import { NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({ ... })
export class ModalPage {

  // Data passed in by componentProps
  @Input() firstName: string;
  @Input() lastName: string;
  @Input() middleInitial: string;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    // componentProps can also be accessed at construction time using NavParams
    console.log(navParams.get('firstName');
  }

  dismiss() {
    // using the injected ModalController this page
    // can "dismiss" itself and optionally pass back data
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss({
      'dismissed': true
    });
  }
}
```

Please make sure to go through the **[lazy loading section](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#lazy-loading)** from the Ionic Docs to see how the modal page should be imported by the pages that are going to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Already pass the origin as extras when navigating forward - then it will be known on page 4 and can be used to return extras to a specific page. It's pretty simple and does not require a modal dialog workaround, which had not been asked for.